# Content-editable <span> tag unselects when the mouse button is released

Tags: javascript, jquery, contenteditable

I'm trying to use a content-editable span tag as a variable-width inline text input box. Everything is working fine, except I can't get it to select the whole text when I focus on the box. Tabbing to the editable span works fine, but when I click it, the mouse-up event seems to unselect the selection I just made. I'm using google chrome latest on Ubuntu.

http://jsfiddle.net/6b3tP/

Here's the HTML:

```
<div>
    Inline editable <span contenteditable="true">spans</span> are hard to select.
</div>
```

And here's the JS:

```
$('span').focus(function() {
    var text_node = this.firstChild;
    var text = $(this).text();
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.setStart(text_node, 0);
    range.setEnd(text_node, text.length);
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    sel.addRange(range);
});
```

Comment: Stays selected after mouse up - Chrome / Mac

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest delaying doing the selecting using `window.setTimeout()` to allow the dust to settle before doing anything. You can also simplify the code a little.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6b3tP/1/

Code:

```
$('span').focus(function() {
    var span = this;
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        var range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNodeContents(span);
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        sel.addRange(range);
    }, 1);
});
```